Vector spaces and subspaces - word problem
The cake factory should form the production of dough and fillings. In order to achieve various tastes, the ingredients in the dough are flour, sugar, vanilla and cocoa in various proportions, and in the fillings milk, chocolate, sugar and jam in various proportions. Create a base vector space for cake production and show that the subspaces of dough and fillings form a direct sum.
This is my work:
Let the dough ingredients be:
$$\eqalign{
  & {v_1} = {\left[ {1000} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {v_2} = {\left[ {0100} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {v_3} = {\left[ {0010} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {v_4} = {\left[ {0001} \right]^T} \cr} $$
Analogue to that, the filling ingredients are:
$$\eqalign{
  & {w_1} = {\left[ {1000} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {w_2} = {\left[ {0100} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {w_3} = {\left[ {0010} \right]^T}  \cr 
  & {w_4} = {\left[ {0001} \right]^T} \cr} $$
The basis for the vector space of dough and fillings combined is formed by the union of the two sets of ingredient vectors:
$${\cal B} = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}$$
Do I now need to remove the linearly dependent vectors from here?
Also, how do I prove that the subspaces form a direct sum?

You can't have the fillings use the same vectors as you use for the dough; the dimension of your vectors are too small; instead you should represent them as length 8 column vectors. Otherwise, the vector $[2,0,0,0]^T$ could represent two lots of flour, two lots of  milk, or one lot of flour and one lot of milk. Therefore, as it stands modelling it this way does not make sense.

So I need to represent them like this: for example,
milk = $${\left[ {00001000} \right]^T}$$

Yes; then you can go about showing the sum is direct.

Okay, thank you. Just one more question, could you write out the basis?

It would be too long to write in a comment most probably but it is simply the standard basis; i.e the set of length 8 column vectors with a 1 in one position and 0's elsewhere.

This problem is really weird, this could mean you have negative ingredients, also it should be « create a basis such that the sub spaces of doughs and fillings form a vector space »

I agree, but I copied it exactly from my textbook.
